# while working with the calendar the date is not being select

Tags: java, selenium

This is the code which I was trying to execute but failed.What I was trying to do is that when I was trying to select the date from returning calendar,then the date is not  being selected.Though I used the same procedure for selecting the date from departure calendar.Let me know where I am wrong.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://easemytrip.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("FromSector")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ulfrom']/li[text()='DEL-Delhi, 
     India']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("Editbox13")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='toautoFill']/ul/li[text()='CCU-
     Kolkata, India']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("ddate")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("frth_5_21/04/2017")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Round Trip']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("rdate")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='frth_6_22/04/2017']")).click();`
```

here is the code for selecting the return calendar.

```html
<div id="rdatelbl" class="retu-date-n">
<div class="fon-txt2">RETURN (Optional) </div>
<div id="divRtnCal" onclick="getTextboxName('rdate');return Fillcalendar();">
<input id="rdate" class="inpu-sec-n1 hide-ddate round-but1" type="text" readonly="" style="" placeholder="Choose Date" name="" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
<input id="hdn1" type="hidden" name="hdn1"/>
<input id="hdn" type="hidden" value="rdate"/>
</div>
<div class="clr"/>
</div>
</div>
```

this is the html code to select the date from  returning calendar.

```html
<div class="days">
<ul>
<li id="fiv_0_23/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
23
<span class="up-date">18465</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_1_24/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
24
<span class="up-date">18465</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_2_25/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
25
<span class="up-date">22094</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_3_26/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
26
<span class="up-date">56332</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_4_27/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
27
<span class="up-date">18551</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_5_28/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
28
<span class="up-date">22169</span>
</li>
<li id="fiv_6_29/04/2017" class="up-date" onclick="SelectDate(this.id)" style="visibility:false">
29
<span class="up-date">18550</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you don't have to write `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` after every statement, this is used only once at the beginning when a new page loads.

Now try following code, you have to provide Explicit wait for elements which take more time to load:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();


driver.get("https://easemytrip.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("FromSector")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new  WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement from = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ulfrom']/li[2]")));
from.click();

driver.findElement(By.id("Editbox13")).click();

WebElement to = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='toautoFill']/ul/li[5]")));
to.click();

driver.findElement(By.id("ddate")).click();

WebElement fromDate = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvcalendar']//ul/li[contains(text(),'21')]")));
fromDate.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Round Trip']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("rdate")).click();
WebElement toDate = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvcalendar']//ul/li[contains(text(),'24')]")));
toDate.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using implicit wait conditions at many places. If you are setting one time it will be exist till the life of the WebDriver object instance so no need of declaring at multiple places.

Try below code:

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://easemytrip.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("FromSector")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ulfrom']/li[text()='DEL-Delhi, India']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Editbox13")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='toautoFill']/ul/li[text()='CCU-Kolkata, India']")).click();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("frth_5_21/04/2017"))); 
   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('frth_5_21/04/2017').click()");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Round Trip']")).click();
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("rdate")));
   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('rdate').click()");   
   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('frth_6_22/04/2017').click()");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Search Flight']")).click();
```

Let me know if it works for you